# Remove related NAs

Tags: r

Previously had a question about creating new dataframes based on related missing NAs. If an NA was at an odd index, that index + the next were removed, if it was even, that index - the previous were removed. Here is the code:

```
is.odd <- function(x) x %% 2 == 1
apply(new, 1, function(x) {
    toremove <-which(is.na(x))
    toremove1<-sapply(toremove,function(x) ifelse(is.odd(x),x+1,x-1) )
    ref[,!(1:ncol(ref) %in% c(toremove,toremove1)),drop=F]
})
```

I am trying to rewrite this for a similar purpose now to remove the NAs from the dataframe new, but print each row as a separate dataframe. I really hate how R handles looping with the apply family and can't figure this out. For example:

```
  var1  var2  var3 var4
1  a     NA    c    1
2  d     e     f    2
3  NA    h     I    3
```

becomes three dataframes:

```
  var3  var4
1   c      1
```

and

```
  var1  var2  var3 var4
2  d     e     f    2
```

and

```
     var3 var4
3     I    3
```

As an update to this, can someone recommend a good R book for people with a c/c++ background?

Comment: have a look at `split`

Comment: Is that chunk of code (which doesn't run because `ref` is undefined) relevant to the problem?

Comment: Also, using `apply` on a data.frame is not recommended. `apply` coerces it to a matrix first. And matrices have to have the same data type

Comment: @Spacedman ref was another datamframe. The code works for a different purpose. Creating new dataframes of ref based on missing NAs + related value of new. I'm trying to re-write the code to work only on new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy your data and create a data.frame:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "var1  var2  var3 var4
1  a     NA    c    1
2  d     e     f    2
3  NA    h     I    3")
```

Find the columns and rows that have NA values:

```
c <- col(df)[is.na(df)]
r <- row(df)[is.na(df)]
```

Get the correct adjacent column conditioned on even/odd:

```
d <- ifelse(c %% 2 == 1, c + 1, c - 1)
```

Loop over the rows that just have NAs to modify them:

```
modified <- lapply(seq_along(r), function(i) {
  remove <- -(c(d[i], c[i]))
  df[r[i], remove, drop=F]
})
```

Simply drop the rows with NAs to get the others

```
unmodified <- split(df[-r, ], (1:nrow(df))[-r])
```

Do whatever you want with your lists of data.frames

### Edit:

Here's the output

```
> modified
[[1]]
  var3 var4
3    I    3

[[2]]
  var3 var4
1    c    1

> unmodified
$`2`
  var1 var2 var3 var4
2    d    e    f    2
```

### Edited to account for multiple NAs in a row:

```
c <- col(df)[is.na(df)]
r <- row(df)[is.na(df)]
d <- ifelse(c %% 2 == 1, c + 1, c - 1)
```

Aggregate all column indices by the rows:

```
ids <- split(cbind(d, c), r)
na.rows <- unique(sort(r))

modified <- lapply(seq_along(na.rows), function(i) {
  df[na.rows[i], -(ids[[i]]), drop=F]
})

unmodified <- split(df[-na.rows, ], (1:nrow(df))[-na.rows])
```

### Edit to put list in same order as original `data.frame`:

You can slot the modified lists in a new list by simply indexing the new list appropriately.

```
recombined <- list()
recombined[na.rows] <- modified
recombined[(1:nrow(df))[-na.rows]] <- unmodified
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. Modified returns far more rows than actually exists and the NAs are not removed.

Comment: Did you modify the code? It produces the output you request.

Comment: I'm using the code on different data, but the code is the same. I have roughly 108 rows and I'm getting 390 rows from modified. hmm

Comment: It likely has to do with multiple NAs in the same row. Can this happen?

Comment: Yeah. Every single variable in a row can have an NA value.

Comment: Almost there. My only issue is that each row needs to be in the same order as dataframes within the list. Each new dataframe in the list corresponds to another dataframe in another list based on sequence. I should have phrased my question better.

Comment: I owe you. By chance can you recommend a good R book for people with a c/c++ background? I keep trying to write code and end up making it way more complex than R needs.

Comment: "The Art of R Programming" by Matloff would be a good choice. It's a few years old now, but it does a great job of explaining the apply family of functions. Here is a pdf of it: http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/132/NSPpart.pdf